# How to display Google Maps with data from template

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ember.js

I have a array of maps with each a latitude and longitide value.

In EmberJS I want to display a google map of each map in the array.

I guess I need a component which takes a latitude and longitude parameter and then displays the map. But how can I achieve this in EmberJS? I'm just starting out with Ember so I don't really have a good clue about this all.

I'm now using ember-g-maps, but I'm running into some trouble:

I want to pass in parameters for lat & lng:

```
{{g-map lat={{selectedMap.gmap_lat_center}} lng={{selectedMap.gmap_long_center}} zoom=12}}
```

I also tried:

```
{{g-map lat=selectedMap.gmap_lat_center lng=selectedMap.gmap_long_center zoom=12}}
```

Both aren't working, how can I accomplish this?

EDIT: seems like I had a typo, the second option is working well.

Comment: Okay, seems you've figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ember-g-map`](https://github.com/asennikov/ember-g-map) addon lets you do that by using just:

```
{{g-map lat=37.7833 lng=-122.4167}}
```

Comment: And how can I pass a variable into lat & lng? Edited the OP for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Embedded Version of Google maps like this

```
<iframe src={{mapURL}} style="width:100%;height:450px;"></iframe>

mapURL: function() {
    return "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=" + this.get('model').get('address').get('city') + ',+' + this.get('model').get('address').get('street') + "," + this.get('country') + "&key=" + "googleAPIKey";
}.property(''),
```